# What is a named function in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm confused about "named function".

We define a method by `def`, and the name of the method comes after `def`.

e.g.`def m() = () => ()` We can say the name of this method is `m`. "Named method" is easy to understand, and I'm sure, there is no anonymous method.

I see explanations of "anonymous function" everywhere.
I know an anonymous function is an instance of a function type, and we can easily find examples of an anonymous function.

Then, a named function must also be an instance of a function type.

I try to give an example myself here.
e.g. `val f = () => ()` I suppose that the name of this function is `f`. And so, there is a named function here.

But when I use tool JD-GUI to decompile the class file, it seems to me that `f` is not a name, but a `ObjectRef`.

Does concept "named function" make sense? I'm totally messed up.

Comment: In what context did you encounter the phrase "named function"?

Comment: It is unclear to me what your confusion is about. Are you not understanding how a function value works?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin In Scala Language Specification, 6.20 Return Expressions, it says, 'A return expression return e must occur inside the body of some enclosing named method or function.' I think "named" is used specifically here. To emphasize that the method or function must have a name.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "named function" in Scala. Functions never have names, methods always have names, classes may or may not have names. I think traits and singleton objects always have names, also variables always have names. However, *nested functions* (i.e. a `def` inside a `def`) have names!

Comment: @汪李之: The SLS unfortunately uses the term "function" rather loosely, sometimes to refer to function objects, sometimes to refer to methods, sometimes to refer to both.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov In fact, I'm trying to find out the target function or method of a return expression in anonymous function. And it seems that name is an important affection.e.g. var g: () => Unit = () => return. Is the target of the return here function g? Or, perhapsm 'funcion g' itself is not a valid term.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks. 'There is no such thing as a "named function" in Scala. Functions never have names.' This helps me a lot. In fact, I have come up with the same idea that "Functions never have names". I just can't confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "named function" refers for example to *nested functions* defined with the `def` keyword. Consider the following example where this makes a difference:

```
def foo: Int = {
  val f: Int => Int = x => return x
  f(58)
  42
}

println(foo) // returns 58
```

The `x => return x` part here is the body of an anonymous function literal. The fact that the function literal is assigned to the variable with name `f` has no influence on the `return` statement: when the `return` is reached, the whole method `foo` returns. In this case, it returns `58`, and the `42` is never reached.

However, this is different for a *named* nested function:

```
def bar: Int = {
  def f(x: Int): Int = {
    return x
  }
  f(58)
  42
}

println(bar) // returns 42
```

Here, the `return` leaves only the nested function `f`, not the whole `bar`-method. The expression `f(58)` in statement position evaluates to `58` and is then ignored. The method `bar` then returns `42`.

The word "function" makes more sense than the word "method" in this context. For example, the nested function `f` is not really tied to some class other than the class that encloses `bar`, and it cannot be invoked on instances of class that encloses the method `bar`, therefore it might be preferable to call it "function" rather than "method".

Comment: `f` is not a function, it's a method.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Interesting, [Scala Tour from 2008](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/116.html) called it "nested function". The [current version of Scala Tour](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/nested-functions.html) calls it "nested method". I personally prefer the name "nested function", because I don't see any objects on which `f` could be invoked, but if the current official guideline is to call it "nested methods", I'm OK with that too.

Comment: That's an interesting idea and may be right, but the terms are used loosely. Maybe methods are members, but overloading resolution talks about functions, for example. Method type vs function type doesn't really help here.

Answer (score 1):

> Does concept "named function" make sense?

The specification states:

> A return expression `return e` must occur inside the body of some enclosing **named method** or function.

The named part refers only to the method, not the function. Although as @som-snytt elaborates, *we can have* named functions as well:

```
object A extends Function1[Int, Int]
```

Would be regarded as named function.

### Edit:

Contacted Lightbend, this is the reply regarding the "named method or function" part of the spec definition:

> This is a spec bug — it should just say “method”. There is
>   unfortunately some confusion in the spec between “method” and
>   “function”. You can see an instance of this right above the passage on
>   return expressions, where the scalprod method is called a “function”.
>   I’ll submit a PR to clarify the section around non-local returns.

To answer your question, you should only regard method as to the scoping rules of a return expression.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what the second part of this statement means? If the "named" part refers only to method, then the second part seems to say *"A return expression `return e` must occur inside the body of some enclosing function"*. But I'm not sure how to interpret that, because for example `val c = { val f: Int => Int = { x => return x }; f(42) }` produces a compilation error "return outside method definition". What functions are meant by the second part of the statement? Is it just inadvertent usage of the legacy nomenclature `nested function -> nested method`?

Comment: The spec goes on, "the apply method of an anon fun does not count as a named function." So this answer cannot be adequate.

Comment: @som-snytt Would you say that the spec is problematic as it intermixes "named functions" with "named methods" interchangeably? Otherwise I can't make much sense out if it.

Comment: This is clearly a named function `object X extends Function1[Int,Int] {...}`. Also the companion of a case class, often. But it's an apply method. I don't know if that is why they gave the distinction undue weight here.

Comment: @som-snytt The companion of a case class is a named function? How so?

Comment: In the same sense as `X`, case companion extends FunctionN by default. Today there is a PR to erase this nomenclature difference, so history (future history) proves you right. Edit: just re-read your answer, plus one.